# Logging intermediary results in stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, logging

I have a stored procedures that calls many other stored procedures and I would like to log intermediary results after each SP executed.

Is it any other better option that using a local or global temporary table and to insert rows in that table? I'm thinking it is not so good if the initial SP is executed in parallel by different users.

Comment: What kind of results do you want to log? Is it on a per user basis? Do the logs need to persist as a history?

Comment: Errors, warnings, debug info, etc... I would like just to return a single resultset with info about SP execution...

Comment: Why not just log into a real table then, What kind of volume are you expecting?

Comment: @DanielE. I'm talking about about 30-40 rows. Yes, it could be an idea. Then this table should be maintained, create indexes on, etc.

Comment: i mean volume of calls to the outer SP

Comment: What about the case it would return 100 rows and get executed 1000 times per day?

Comment: How often are you reporting against it? How long do you intend to keep a specific logged record?

Comment: I don't need a history, I just need to return a single result set so it can be binded to a grid...

Answer (score 1):

I would log directly into a physical table, but for the kind of volume you are looking at a tmp table wouldn't strain anything much either.

This comment changes my answer.
"I don't need a history, I just need to return a single result set so it can be binded to a grid"

Absolutely use a local temp table, do not worry about side by side calls in this case.

Answer (score 0):

create a session table in the main sp and log all the calls as you wish and at the end move it to a physical table with an ID to identify

Comment: "Session table"? Is that a concept in SQL Server?

Comment: What about the case when the same user executed the SP multiple times?

Comment: local temp table is session table